# finding only perfect pth roots and nothing else efficiently

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

Let *l* an *r* be the given range.
We know that number of numbers within *l* and *r* such that it can be represented as x^p is given by

`floor(powl((long double)r,1.0/(long double)p) - ceil(powl((long double)l,1.0/(long double)p)`

Now the real problem,
I need all the numbers between *l* and *r*, *x*, such that only ***pth* root of x exists** and nothing else.
**For example**, within a range *1 - 20* and **p=2** the valid numbers are 
{4,9}
The reason why 16 didn't occur in the set is because 16 can be represented as 2^4.

Now I want to perform a repeated inclusion-exclusion principle on the range and find numbers such that they can be represented as to the power p only!

Comment: @YvesDaoust elaborated a bit more

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @High Performance Mark why not can a pow function be used here and along with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: Your question is still not clear, either as mathematics or as a computer program. What exactly is the input, and what will be the output? Please give us a full example, not the partial ones you have given. Also, what work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? Show us your attempted code so far.

Comment: @RoryDaulton This is the best elaboration you can get.

Comment: You might have better luck if you wrote a brute force algorithm that does what you want, and then we help you figure out how to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sieve:

Maintain a list of prime powers of integers, which you initialize with 2².

Iteratively

- compute the square of the next integer;
- at the same time, take the smallest element of the list and raise it to the next prime power;
- depending on the smallest of the two, lengthen the list or update the smallest element;
- in case of ties, give priority to the element in the list;
- loop.

.

```
2^2 (<3^2)
2^3 (<3^2)
2^3 3^2 (<4^2)
2^4 3^2 (=4^2)
2^4 3^2 5^2 (<6^2)
2^4 3^3 5^2 (<6^2)
2^5 3^3 5^2 (<6^2)
2^5 3^3 5^3 (<6^2)
...
```

Comment: Can't exactly understand how it goes. Can you please explain?